# When does a distribution admit a closed top-dimensional differential form?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles

Let $M^n$ be a smooth manifold. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a $k$-dimensional integrable distribution on $M$. Denote by $\mathcal{D}^\bot\to M$ the vector bundle which is spanned by the differentials of the set of first integrals of $\mathcal{D}$. That is, at a point $p$ we have $\mathcal{D}^\bot|_p = \left<\mathrm{d}f\ \Big|\ \forall\xi\in\mathcal{D}|_p\colon\xi(f) = 0\right>$.

Then for any point $p\in M$ there are functions $f^1_p, \ldots, f^{n - k}_p$ such that in a neighbourhood of $p$ the differential $(n - k)$-form $\omega_{(p)} := \mathrm{d}f^1_p\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}f^{n - k}_p$ is nowhere vanishing and the vector bundle $\mathcal{D}^\bot$ equals $\left<\mathrm{d}f^1_p, \ldots, \mathrm{d}f^{n - k}_p\right>$, so $\omega_{(p)}$ is "top-dimensional".

Clearly, we have $\mathrm{d}\omega_{(p)} = 0$. Also, each differential $(n - k)$-form $\tau\in\bigwedge^{n - k}\mathcal{D}^\bot|_p$
is proportional to $\omega_{(p)}$.

As one can see, the existence of such $\omega_{(p)}$ for each $p\in M$ is a local condition. What I wonder is when a similar condition is met globally.

To be precise, the question is the following. When does there exist a nowhere vanishing $(n - k)$-dimensional differential form $\omega$ such that $\mathrm{d}\omega = 0$ and at each point $p\in M$ the form $\omega$ is proportional to $\omega_{(p)}$ (or, equivalently, $\mathrm{d}\omega = 0$ and $\forall p\in M\colon\omega|_p\in\bigwedge^{n - k}\mathcal{D}^\bot|_p$)?

This obviously always holds for $k = 0, n$ (a constant function and a volume form will suffice). However, I have not been able to think of (and prove) a criterion even for $k = 1$. In particular, I have tried using a partition of unity but have not succeeded.

Comment: Using a partition of unity sounds promising for something like this, what difficulty did you find when you tried that approach?

Comment: @basel I tried to multiply each "local" form by the corresponding function from the partition of unity. However, the problem I encountered is that the resulting form is not closed since the function depends on all coordinates, not just _f_-s.

Comment: An approach that may lead to the solution is to observe that each transition map acts on each local form as a multiplication by a function. Thus we can multiply every local form by some factor so that the local forms agree on the intersections of charts. However, it is not clear whether the resulting differential form is closed.